# Opening a connection within Task.Factory.StartNew

Tags: c#, task, sqlconnection

Hello I am getting an error on the objConn.Open():

> A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Thread was being aborted.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    using (SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(Options.GetConnectionString()))
    {
        objConn.Open();
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(Options.SqlText, objConn);
        SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
    }
});
```

Any ideas why I am getting this error? I can't seem to figure it out

Comment: Does this work on main thread?

Comment: Put a try/catch into your task and get the real problem.

Comment: Opening the connection does not work in the main thread. The message that comes back is: Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.

Comment: What does `Options.GetConnectionString()` do?

Comment: Why use `Task.Factory.StartNew` with sync methods instead of using `await objConn.OpenAsync()` and `await comm.ExecuteReaderAsync()` ?